# gnuplot: how to set the different fill and border colors for `with points`?

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to achieve a similar [effect](https://clauswilke.com/dataviz/color-basics.html#color-as-a-tool-to-highlight) in gnuplot.

[image: effect]

Here is what I tried:

```
unset key
set style line 11 lc rgb '#808080' lt 1
set border 3 ls 11
set tics nomirror
set grid

set style line 1 lc rgb '#808080' pt 9 ps 3
set style line 2 lc rgb '#808080' pt 20 ps 3
set style line 3 lc rgb '#BD3828' pt 7 ps 3

set yrange [4:9]
$data << EOD
5   5.1
5.3 6.8
6   6
EOD

$data2 << EOD
5 5
7 7
8 6
EOD

$data3 << EOD
5.5 7
6 6
7 7.1
EOD

plot $data u 1:2 w points ls 1, $data2 u 1:2 w points ls 2, \
$data3 u 1:2 w points ls 3
```

[image]

As we can see, points can be overlapped. Then how can we darken the overlap areas?

---

A possible solution is to set transparency (e.g., `lc rgb '#80808080'`), but it will also make both border and filling transparent. So how to set the different fill and border colors for `with points`?

Another solution is to use `set object`, but we need to do more work to read data from files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest you could come to what you describe is to draw the points in two passes.

**First pass**: draw using a point type that produces only the outlines (point types N = 4 6 8 10 12 ...).

**Second pass**: draw using the corresponding point type N+1 that produces only the interior, using the same color but adding an alpha channel value to make it partially transparent.

```
set print $RAND1
do for [i = 1:50] { print rand(0), rand(0) }
unset print
set print $RAND2
do for [i = 1:50] { print rand(0), rand(0) }
unset print

set pointsize 4

plot $RAND1 with points pt  8 lc rgb "#00b8860b", \
         '' with points pt  9 lc rgb "#AAb8860b", \
     $RAND2 with points pt  6 lc rgb "#00c04000", \
         '' with points pt  7 lc rgb "#AAc04000"
```

[image]

Comment: Than how to generate 1 key for two passes?

Comment: @chenzhongpu `plot ... pt 8 title "first dataset", ... pt 9 notitle, ... pt 6 title "second dataset", ... pt 7 notitle`.